# Find MAC address of stolen Dell Laptop

Tags: laptop, mac-address, dell-vostro, anti-theft

My Dell Laptop has been stolen. I have the address service tag number and serial number. My laptop is more then 6 year and a few months old. I have contacted Dell Support but they said that they were unable to find the system MAC Address because the system age is more then 6 year and there is no other way to find it. My laptop contains lots of precious data. I need to recover that.

As I know, only MAC address can be used to track my laptop.

Does anybody know anything about this? Can I can find my MAC address in any way ? If somebody has an idea please suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not write it somewhere then you are unlikely to find it back.
One of the very few way to get it is to consult [ARP cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) of computers connected on the same networks your laptop connected recently, and not restarted meanwhile.

You must know that it is very hard to locate a computer given one of its MAC addresses since they are only visible on the same network the computer is currently connected to. You can not use it through the Internet.

Another way could be to use online accounts your computer is configured to auto-join and track activity from there (online antivirus account if any, google connection logs if a google account is automatically used, maybe Microsoft Office 365 or Skype account, etc). You will then get public IP addresses the police can work with, or you can give those details to the police for it to ask any activity to the service provider if they don't give those data to end users.

Comment: Thanks for reply. `ARP cache` i have no idea this thing. Previously I have logged in with my Skype account. Is there any way to get MAC address through Skype account. I have searched but not find anything. I have got gmail history but they provide only for 2 days. Is there any possibility to find 10 days gmail history ?

Answer (score 1):

1- Go to your router settings, and look for DHCP assigned addresses. If it's lease time is not expired yet, you can see your MAC address and IP assigned to it.

2- If you had any other computer in home that connected and/or pinged each other, in CMD run `arp -a` and it will show you the MAC addresses of connected network devices.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have used Dongle for internet and sometimes connected with my android phone.

Comment: Is there any way to find out with phone ?

Comment: If you used a 3G/4G dongle for internet, any connection (e.g. skype, etc...) used the MAC address of your dongle.

There are many tips and tricks to recover information from a rooted Android device... Take a look at [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996351/wi-fi-tethering-how-to-get-list-of-connected-clients)

Comment: I have lost also that dongle. But sometime i have connected my laptop with My Android phone also and gmail and skype are logged their.

Comment: Gmail provide only 2 days history and skype i'm able to get any things useful when i was searched.

Comment: Did you see the link I sent? To check your phone's DHCP list? (consider that it may not be there if the lease time is expired!!!)

Comment: please check i didn't see any link.

Comment: [This article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996351/wi-fi-tethering-how-to-get-list-of-connected-clients)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49655/discussion-between-saveen-and-amirhossein).

Comment: Also see [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117514/wifi-hotspot-dnsmasq-no-dhcp-ack). You see the line? "DHCPACK(wlan0) 192.168.43.127 c0:bd:d1:4a:3a:0f android-e55b7f59c0dfe96"? that's where an IP is assigned to a MAC address.

Comment: What's up? You summoned me

Comment: yes i need your help i'm trying to open `dnsmasq` inside bin but not able open this file through command line adb.

Comment: copy and upload it somewhere and send me the link

Comment: actually i'm not able to do anything with file

Comment: If you have root access and r/w access to folder, you can open/copy it somewhere else. What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

look in the system log of a router you connected thru. If you set static addresses it will be even easier to find.

Comment: Thanks but i'm using Sim based Dongle for Internet. I have logged my gmail and skype their. Is there any way to check my Mac address through these things ?

Answer (score 1):

If you used an USB dongle to connect to the Internet the chances are very low to find what was your MAC address unless that dongle stores it somewhere but each dongle is different.

Also keep in mind that even if you find your MAC address it will most likely be still impossible to find the laptop. The MAC address does not get past the router so the websites that you connect do not know your MAC address.

The chances you will get your laptop back are very little, with the MAC address or not.

This is why is extremely important to make constant backups so that you will have the data available.

Comment: I have connected my laptop to wi-fi dongle and i have lost that dongle also.

Comment: @Saveen well... then there is no way to know the MAC address of the laptop. Also the MAC address is not traceable. The websites that you have visited do not know your MAC address... and if the thief will use your laptop to connect to the Internet the websites HE will visit will NOT know his MAC address so even if you knew your MAC address it would NOT have been of any help.

Comment: okay thanks but is there any way to police can trace ?

Comment: i have lost my dongle too and dongle have IMEI number but i haven't that one in my invoice copy. I have some serial number. That dongle is Huawei company. I have talked to customer service but they said we haven't permission to provide you IMEI number. Is there any way to get IMEI number so i can track my dongle. So it help me to find it.

Comment: Let me understand. The thief who stole your laptop also stole your USB Dongle ?  If it is the same thief and if he uses the that specific dongle to connect to the Internet then the Dongle may be located. You have to go to the police and the police will go to the company who made the dongle and will get the IMEI from that dongle.

Comment: okay somebody stole my bag and even my backup external HDD also in that bag.